# JMS Inbound Gateway - error handling when reply destination queue send is not possible

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

We have an EIP flow which uses annotation-based `spring:4.2.x` APIs, `spring-integration:4.2.x` APIs and `spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.0` APIs to receive messages from a Websphere MQ Queue, do some processing and finally return responses to another Websphere MQ Queue. For this flow, we are using a `JMS Inbound Gateway` to synchronously receive messages from one queue, process them and send the responses back to another queue.

The `JMS Inbound Gateway` is configured with an `errorChannel` so that `RuntimeException`s are routed to it (this works fine). However during tests, when we purposely apply a PUT_INHIBIT on the flow's response Websphere MQ queue (i.e. to cause the flow to be unable to send responses back to the reply queue), the spring logs show the following `WARNING` log message:

`WARN ... - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
javax.jms.JMSException: MQJMS2007: failed to send message to MQ queue.`

We know we can remove that `WARNING` log by configuring an `ErrorHandler` on the `MLC` itself but, the reason this is causing us problems is that when we route a response back, we actually route using a `.routeToRecipients()` call with `.setIgnoreFailures(false)` and two recipients - the first recipient routing to the `JMS Inbound Gateway`'s `replyChannel` and the second routing to a post-send flow so that we can do DB updates, etc. The idea here being that if the first recipient send fails (i.e. when the response queue is not available), the post-send flow doesn't execute but instead an error handling flow executes instead (e.g. `errorChannel` flow). But in the described error scenario, we see the warning log, and the flow's post-send flow still executes instead of the `errorChannel`'s flow...

It is as though, at this point, the `JMS Inbound Gateway`'s `errorChannel` no longer applies. Is this correct? And is this intended behaviour? And if it is, does this mean that we should use `Inbound/Outbound Adapter`s instead of an `Inbound Gateway` for our response post-send intent?

JMS MLC Configuration:

```
@Bean( destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer serviceMLC() throws Exception {

    DefaultMessageListenerContainer mlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    mlc.setAutoStartup(false);
    mlc.setConnectionFactory(serviceCCF);
    mlc.setDestination(requestMqQueue);
    mlc.setAcceptMessagesWhileStopping(false);
    return mlc;
}
```

JMS Inbound Gateway Configuration:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow serviceFlow() {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms
                    .inboundGateway(serviceMLC)
                    .autoStartup(true)
                    .defaultReplyDestination(responseMqQueue)
                    .replyChannel(responseOutCh)
                    .replyTimeout(180000)
                    .correlationKey("JMSCorrelationID")
                    .errorChannel(serviceErrorCh)
                    )
            .channel(serviceInCh)
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the gateway doesn't work that way.

When you send the reply to the gateway, it is queued in the gateway until the thread returns to the gateway; at which time, the reply is picked up and sent. So, the failure to send does not occur until later (after your second recipient flow is invoked).

Yes, to do what you want, you should use channel adapters instead because the failure will run directly on the calling thread.

Comment: Could you point to a sample using Java class please ? (not bean config xml)

Comment: You should not ask unrelated questions in comments on (extremely) old answers. It is also not at all clear what you are asking - a sample of what? Ask a new question with much more clarity.

Comment: It's not unrelated.Your accepted answer does not provide any sample link to do in Java using @Bean That's all

Comment: But it is in the question (`@Bean`). Like I said, asking a new question with more details will help people understand exactly what you need help with. Stack Overflow is not suited for extended commentary (and the admins discourage it).